# Envelopes:listStatusChanges does not return "emailSubject"

Tags: docusignapi

The call to [Envelopes:listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) method, from the DocuSign API,  returns a response that does not contain **emailSubject**, "emailBlurb" etc. Here is the response for the Envelopes object -

```
{
"status": "completed",
"documentsUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/documents",
"recipientsUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/recipients",
"envelopeUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b",
"envelopeId": "7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b",
"customFieldsUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/custom_fields",
"notificationUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/notification",
"statusChangedDateTime": "2017-02-14T15:49:46.9870000Z",
"documentsCombinedUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/documents\/combined",
"certificateUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/documents\/certificate",
"templatesUri": "\/envelopes\/7645477f-4610-4bdf-bdb2-2804ed72fe9b\/templates"
}
```

To get the "emailSubject" I have to iterate through each Envelope object from the *Envelopes:listStatusChanges* method, and use the *Envelopes:Get* method on that envelope to get other information about it. This causes a lot of API calls, depending on how many envelopes there are.

Does anyone know how to retrieve **emailSubject** from the original *Envelopes:listStatusChanges* call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [Envelopes:listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) API does not return the emailSubject/emailBlurb fields.

You can use the [GetSearchFolders](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/) API to retrieve the emailSubject field.

For emailBlurb you will have to query the [GetEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) api for each envelope.

For example, The following GET request retrieves a list of the all the envelopes from 2017-01-01 ordered by Sent date

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/all?from_date=2017-01-01&order_by=sent
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Great solution. I'm assuming this won't count against the GET one envelope per 15 minutes API Limit? since it's not calling

    GET /v2/envelopes/

Comment: Yes it will not account for the 15 min Api limit. Here are the complete API limit rules (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/resource_limits.html) . If you see yourself polling for the same envelope then I suggest you use Docusign Connect. Its much more efficient to retrieve envelope status changes through connect (https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect.htm)

Comment: Here is a an updated URL for Docusign Connect aka Webhooks .. http://docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks